# Using Regex in Python to add quantity identifier before and after Numeric Quantity value

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, python-re

I am using Regex in Python to add quantity identifiers before and after the Numeric Quantity value.

Basically, I have to add **QtyOrd** and **Units** words its not in the text after numeric quantity.

For example:

```
'PartNo-001A description 20 units some other description' => 'PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 units some other description'
'PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 some other description' => 'PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 units some other description'
'PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20' => 'PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 units'
'PartNo-001A QtyOrd 20' => 'PartNo-001A QtyOrd 20 units'
'PartNo-001A 20 units'=> 'PartNo-001A QtyOrd 20 units'
```

The Code am using is below:

```py
import re

def process_QtyOrd( text):
    for x in re.findall("(qtyord [0-9]+ units| [0-9]+ units|qtyord [0-9]+|qtyord[0-9]+units )", text.lower()):
        Text_Intermediate = "OrderQty " + str(re.search("[0-9]+", x).group()) + " Units"
    
    Text_Final = re.sub("(qtyord [0-9]+ units|[0-9]+ units|qtyord [0-9]+|qtyord [0-9]+ units)", Text_Intermediate, text, flags= re.IGNORECASE)

    return Text_Final

text1 = 'PartNo-001A description 20 units some other description'
text2 = '''
Could you please redirect the ticket to the correct sales department so they can provide assistance and a quote for the items
below.

QtyOrd 20 units some other description

''' 
text3 = 'PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 some other description'
text4 = 'PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20'
text5 = 'PartNo-001A QtyOrd 20'
text6 = 'PartNo-001A 20 units'
text7 = ''' 

Could you please redirect the ticket to the correct sales department so they can provide assistance and a quote for the items
below.

QtyOrd 20 units some other description PartNo-001A
 
''' 

text8 = ''' 

Could you please redirect the ticket to the correct sales department so they can provide assistance and a quote for the items
below.

PartNo-001A

QtyOrd 
20

'''
```

Then:

```
print(process_QtyOrd(text1))
print(process_QtyOrd(text2))
print(process_QtyOrd(text3))
print(process_QtyOrd(text4))
print(process_QtyOrd(text5))
print(process_QtyOrd(text6))
print(process_QtyOrd(text7))
print(process_QtyOrd(text8))
```

For `text8` the code is not working.
Can you please help me out on this?

The output should like this:

```
1. PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 Units some other description
 

2. Could you please redirect the ticket to the correct sales department so they can provide assistance and a quote for the items
below.

QtyOrd 20 Units some other description


3. PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 Units some other description
4. PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 Units
5. PartNo-001A QtyOrd 20 Units
6. PartNo-001A QtyOrd 20 Units
 

7. Could you please redirect the ticket to the correct sales department so they can provide assistance and a quote for the items
below.

QtyOrd 20 Units some other description PartNo-001A
 

8. Could you please redirect the ticket to the correct sales department so they can provide assistance and a quote for the items
below.

PartNo-001A

QtyOrd 
20
units
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
import re
text = r'PartNo-001A description 20 units some other description'
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(?:qtyord\s*(\d+)(?:\s*units)?|(\d+)\s*units)\b', re.I)
Text_Final = pattern.sub(r'QtyOrd \1\2 units', text)
print(Text_Final)
# => PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 units some other description
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/57VQdG/2) and [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/sazWDp).

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `qtyord`
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(\d+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): one or more digits
  - `(?:\s*units)?` - an optional group matching zero or more whitespaces and `units` word (add `?` after `s` if you also want to match `unit` in singular)
- `|` - or

  - `(\d+)` - Group 2 (referred to with `\2` from the replacement pattern): one or more digits
  - `\s*units` - zero or more whitespaces and `units` word (add `?` after `s` if you also want to match `unit` in singular)
- `)` - end of the group
- `\b` - word boundary

Comment: The code is running fine. Just for the other numbers its also added to QtyOrd and Unit. For. Eg.  'PartNo-001A description 20 units some other 3 mm description' =>  'PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 units some other QtyOrd 3 units mm description'. QtyOrd and Unit should be only for the numeric quantity and not for any other numeric value. Input text may contain lot of numeric value. but It will add only for Quantity

Comment: @SafayetKarim Sorry, the second alternative does not need an optional group.  I have updated the code and demos.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your expected result for text8 is `OrderQty 20 Units`,
not `QtyOrd 20 units`, would you please try:

```
def process_QtyOrd(text):
    m = re.match(r'^(.*?)(qtyord\s*\d+\s*units|\d+\s+units|qtyord\s+\d+)(.*)$', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    if m:
        str= re.sub(r'\D*(\d+)\D*', r'OrderQty \1 Units', m.group(2))
        text = m.group(1) + str + m.group(3)
    return text
```

- The `re.match` breaks the input `text` into three substrings:
  the portion in interest we want to modify, the leading substring, and
  the trailing substring.
- I have used `\s` instead of   (whitespace) to match newline characters.
- The portion in interest is captured by `m.groups(2)`. Then we can
  modify it with `re.sub()` function.
- The final `text` is the concatenation of the substrings above.

**[Update]**

Would you please try the following:

```
def process_QtyOrd(text):
    text = re.sub(r'(qtyord\s*\d+\s*units|\d+\s+units|qtyord\s+\d+)', lambda m: re.sub(r'\D*(\d+)\D*', r'QtyOrd \1 Units', m.group(1)), text, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    return text
```

Now it will work if the text contains multiple patterns. I've changed the word `OrderQty` to `QtyOrd` in the replacement text.

- Instead of the `re.match()` function in the previous answer, I've used
  `re.sub()` function to replace all the occurrences of the pattern in the text at once.
- The lambda function is introduced to evaluate the replacement part as an
  expression.

**[Update2]**

If you want to include decimal numbers, please try the following:

```
def process_QtyOrd(text):
    text = re.sub(r'(qtyord\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*units|\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+units|qtyord\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', lambda m: re.sub(r'\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\D*', r'QtyOrd \1 Units', m.group(1)), text, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    return text
```

The concept is to replace `\d+` with `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` which matches digits followed by optional dot and digits.

Comment: for text8 it should be QtyOrd 20 units, not OrderQty 20 Units

Comment: Your expected result shows "OrderQty 20 Units" from text1 to text7,
while only text8 includes "QtyOrd 20 units". What is the rule to make
the difference?

Comment: Sorry. I think I have written wrongly the output. I need all the text should be QtyOrd and Unit before and after quantity.

Comment: I have checked the code is working fine for one line. But if I want to change for multiple lines then its only works for the first line. Please see the sample input text below: 

text1 ='''   
    
    ITEM NO.   1     QtyOrd 2    UOM   EA   MANUFACTURER   NOV   MANUFACTURER PartNoId PartNo-001A   PartNoId NAME   Coupling   DESCRIPTION   Coupling hub for drawworks lube oil pump


    
    ITEM NO.   1     QtyOrd 2    UOM   EA   MANUFACTURER   NOV   MANUFACTURER PartNoId PartNo-001A   PartNoId NAME   Coupling   DESCRIPTION   Coupling hub for drawworks lube oil pump
''' '''

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It's very clear now. Please give me a little time to update my code.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the modified code. Would you please try it?

Comment: Thanks for the update code. Code is running if I change reOrderQty.DOTALL => re.DOTALL. I think it's a typo mistake.

Comment: Oops, that is a typo (or mouso :). Now corrected. Thank you for testing and responding.

Comment: I have another kind of the same issue. can you plz help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67203956/using-regex-in-python-to-add-partnoid-identifier-before-partno

Comment: Thank you for pointing to me a new question. I suppose Wiktor's answer is good enough and well explained.

Comment: just one update...the above code is running well for integer no but if it's decimal then output is changed. e.g. PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20.00 Units some other description -> PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 Units.QtyOrd 00 Units some other description

Comment: Hello. I've updated my answer with the code according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. it's solved my purpose now.. A big Thanks