# Using Regex in Python to add PartNoId identifier before PartNo-

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regexp-replace

I am using Regex in Python to add PartNoId identifiers before PartNo-.

The Code am using is below:

```
import re
def process_PartNo(text):    
    text = re.sub(r'(PartNo-)', r'PartNoId \1', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    return text
#######################################################################################
text1 = 'PartNo-001A description 20 units some other description'
text2 = 'PartNoId PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 some other description'
text3 = '''
PartNoId
PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20'
'''
text4 = '''
PartNoId

PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20'
'''
text5 = ''' 
PartNoId PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 some other description
PartNoId PartNo-002A description QtyOrd 20 some other description 
'''
text6 = ''' 
PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 some other description
PartNo-002A description QtyOrd 20 some other description 
'''
###########################################################################
print(process_PartNo(text1))
print(process_PartNo(text2))
print(process_PartNo(text3))
print(process_PartNo(text4))
print(process_PartNo(text5))
print(process_PartNo(text6))
```

But in case of ample text where already PartNoId already exits there should not be added again PartNoId

The Output is of the code is as below:

```
PartNoId PartNo-001A description 20 units some other description
PartNoId PartNoId PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 some other description

PartNoId
PartNoId PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20'


PartNoId

PartNoId PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20'

 
PartNoId PartNoId PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 some other description
PartNoId PartNoId PartNo-002A description QtyOrd 20 some other description 

 
PartNoId PartNo-001A description QtyOrd 20 some other description
PartNoId PartNo-002A description QtyOrd 20 some other description
```

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an `if` statement to check if `PartNoId` is `in` the string prior to replacing.

```
def process_PartNo(text):
    if 'PartNoId' not in text:
        text = re.sub(r'(PartNo-)', r'PartNoId \1', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
        return text
    return text
```

This will only run the `re.sub()` if `PartNoId` does not exist in the string already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can optionally match `PartNoId` with whitespace after it, right before `PartNo-`:

```py
def process_PartNo(text):    
    return re.sub(r'(?:PartNoId\s+)?(PartNo-)', r'PartNoId \1', text, flags=re.I)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VxJz4S) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBlVRt/1). Add word boundaries, `\b`, if you need to match whole words only, `r'\b(?:PartNoId\s+)?(PartNo-)'`.

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:PartNoId\s+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of `PartNoId` and then one or more whitespaces
- `(PartNo-)` - Group 1: `PartNo-` text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution